# JS not found - express app - cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google cloud functions with express js to serve up some HTML files. My js files do not show up in the browser. It says 404 not found.

My folder structure

[image: Folder structure]

My HTML file:

```
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="/public/js/auth.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content__container">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="/public/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My app.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");


const app = express();

app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/js")));

exports.admin = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "admin.html"));
});
```

The error in the browser when I invoke the cloud function `admin`

[image: Js not showing in browser]

Functions directory

[image: Functions directory]

Comment: Did you try putting ` src="main.js"` instead of ` src="/public/js/main.js"`?

Comment: yes, it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From where have you exposed the Express app? There must be a HTTP function that should look something like this:

```js
const app = express()
app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/js")));

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
// This is missing? or you are not requesting at this URL
```

When you add the above function, your JS file should be available at the following URL:

```js
'http://localhost:5001/photography-5b191/us-central-1/api/js/main.js'
// notice the function name ('api' in this case) ---->^^^
```

The function name that has exposed the Express app is missing from the URL in the network log that you've shared.

Comment: i dont know why it is missing. Because that url is rendering html but not showing js files.

Comment: @ShahirRiaz that URL will render because you have an API endpoint for that. You have not exposed the public directory via any function? Can you update your question with all the Cloud functions that you have?

Comment: i am using `exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);` but i made another function `admin` to send `admin.html` to browser.

Comment: What could be a better solution?

Comment: @ShahirRiaz try adding the `api` function and changing script URL to: `<script src="'http://localhost:5001/photography-5b191/us-central-1/api/js/main.js'"></script>`

Comment: i get this error in browser `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` the script must be of `type="module"` because i am using `firebase auth`

Comment: @ShahirRiaz can you open the link `http://localhost:5001/photography-5b191/us-central-1/api/js/main.js` directly in browser tab and check if it loads? If it loads and there is no 404, then the original issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to declare app in your js file

```js
const app = express();
```

In your HTML file:

```
<script src="./js/main.js">
```

If `js` is your static/public dir:

```
<script src="./main.js">
```

Also, in your js file:

```js
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "admin.html"));
```

Comment: i corrected the question, in the code i have declared it

Comment: Try these first.